# Is it possible to add text or a toolbar beside the address bar?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser, zendesk

I'm trying to add a text beside the address bar if it's possible. Any recommendations on how to do it?

I would like this text to display whenever the user visits my website.
Will this be an extension?

[Here's a sample image of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G3qM.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, extensions can't do that or anything of the kind. You can add the text into the web page.

Comment: Thanks! So I can't put anything there except for extension icons?